# Unable to load default index page in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Here is the web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <display-name>BulkSMS2</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>BulkSMS2</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/BulkSMS2-servlet.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>BulkSMS2</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/BulkSMS2-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

Dispatcher-Servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.nt.beans" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

And when I run the app, I get 404 error. I have the placed the index.jsp file inside `WEB-INF/pages/index.jsp` folder but still I get the same error. I have checked all the configurations and I am not sure why it is not find the page.

Comment: How are you accessing the index page. Is the request going through a controller. If so post the controller code.

Comment: @ekemchitsiga Its a static page

Comment: if you want an index page it has to be directly accessible. Anything under WEB-INF isn't accessible. You have to put the `index.jsp` directly inside the root of your web app. Also a quick tip you are basically loading your application twice (both the `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet` load the same configuration, basically loading everything twice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of configuration issues with your application. Firstly the way you are specifying your application context.From your config it seems you have one application context BulkSMS2-servlet.xml. Therefore you do not require the root application context. So remove this section in your web.xml

```
 <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/BulkSMS2-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Second issue is with your url mapping /*. It overrides all servlet mappings including jsp handling provided by the container. This means that all requests including requests for jsps is handled by your DispatcherServlet. Change this part

BulkSMS2
    /*

To
       
            BulkSMS2
            /

This overrides the container default servlet handler but does not override special container servlets. To handle static resources add the following line to your BulkSMS2-servlet.xml

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
```

To access your index.jsp as a static resource you need to put it in the root webapp folder outside the WEB-INF folder. However if you want to keep it in WEB-INF folder then your request should be handled by a controller

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController{

  @RequestMapping()
  public String showHomePage(){
     return "index";
  }
}
```

Comment: so I can remove internal view resolver as well? this part: `<bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding below method in your controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String indexPage(ModelMap model) {

        return "index";

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you map the DispatcherServlet to `/*` so it will receive the empty servlet path `/`.

The simplest you can do (IMHO) is to remove the `<welcome-file-list>` block in the web.xml file to simply pass an empty servlet path as default address: it will be processed by Spring-MVC.

Then you just add a SimpleUrlHandlerMapping to map the default URL to a ParameterizedViewController that would just display your view.

So in the dispatcher-servlet context, you add the following beans:

```
<bean id="indexController" p:viewName="index"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"/>
<bean id="simpleUrlHandlerMapping"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <value>
            /=indexController
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

But you have a problem in your web.xml file. You are using same file to initialize the root context (top level `<context-param>` block) and the DispatcherServlet one (`<servlet><init-param>` block). So you will end with two different instances of each and every bean, first in root context latter in child one. That can lead to strange and hard to detect problems... Short story: **don't do that**.